# ASP.Net 4.6.1, MVC5, and Entity 6.x Complexity and Confusion

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an issue that I am not sure how to approach.  I have an MVC5 Application with models generated by entity framework being built and the data relation is fairly complex.

The example would be like below:

1. Fingerprints:

   - Fingerprint Children.

     - Fingerprint Childrens Children.

I can list the actual data/data model if needed, but this is essentially how they relate.  There are 1 to many children for a fingerprint, and 1 to many children for a fingerprints child.

Now the question is how do I properly do the create function for these relationships.  This means that when a fingerprint is inserted, immediately after the children are inserted, and then the childrens children.  I don't understand how I can do this with MVC5, but I'm sure there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your wanting to join the three tables together ?

```
var entryPoint = (from f in dbContext.Fingerprints
                 join fc in dbContext.Fingerprint on fc.FingerPrintID equals f.FingerPrintID
                 join fcc in dbContext.FingerprintsChildrenChildren on e.fingerprintchildrenID equals fc.fingerprintchildrenID
                 where FC.FingerPrintID  == fcc.FingerPrintID
                 select new {
                   whatever you want to select  
                 })





FingerPrint f = new FingerPrint();
FingerPrint fc = new FingerPrints();
FingerprintsChildrenChildren  FCC = FingerprintsChildrenChildren();

f.FingerPrints.add(fc);
fc.FingerPrintsChildrenChildren(FCC)
```

you can then create a DBContext and call save using F and it will save all three objects

Comment: Would that work if I needed to have an HTML table that could dynamically grow/shrink in size for mid and base level items?  Also, what MVC code would I use to handle the "New" operation for all three of these in relation to the view?

Comment: Getting the data is going to be a separate problem to solve with in reference to the HTML table that grows and shinks as for handling a New operation I will update the answer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update your answer!  I think that after doing more and more MVC work and reading tutorials I've gained a better understanding and appreciation of how it works.  understanding that loops and other tools can be used inside of the actual html page has helped tremendously as well.